# App crashes on button click, android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to make a basic calculator that has 4 calculating buttons,the thing is that I am not allowed to use onclickListener but regular calculating methods instead, the calculator crashes when I press the adding button

Here is my Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Operand1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Operand1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    substract = (Button)findViewById(R.id.substract);
    multiply = (Button)findViewById(R.id.multiply);
    divide = (Button)findViewById(R.id.divide);
    result = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

}
public void addMethod(View view) {

   int num1 = Integer.parseInt(Operand1.getText().toString());
   int num2 = Integer.parseInt(Operand2.getText().toString());
   int sum = num1 + num2;
}
```

Comment: plz share the XML layout code.

Comment: Do share your crash log also.